# R - Change value in data frame according to its original value

Tags: r

I currently working on a data frame which contain a column called label which only have value 1 and 0.

For example,

```
x1 | x2 | label
0.1  0.2    1
0.1  0.3    1
0.2  0.5    0
```

How can I convert the value in column label by if label = 1 then label becomes +1 and if label = 0 then label becomes -1

This is a structure than i wanted

```
x1 | x2 | label
0.1  0.2    +1
0.1  0.3    +1
0.2  0.5    -1
```

Also, the column label is currently a numeric type, I will need to change it to factor to proceed with my tasks.

Here is the code for changing it to factor.

```
df$label <- factor(df$label)
```

Normally, I would run a for loop to change it. However, sometimes there would be a situation where there are many labels which result in me writing a long for loop which I think it is not effective.

In this case, what would be an effective solution to this.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try `c('-1', '+1')[(df1$label + 1)]`  Or use the `factor` approach `factor(df1$label, labels = c('-1', '+1'))`

Comment: you got it, would you like to post your answer?, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this by numeric indexing to replace the values

```
c('-1', '+1')[(df1$label + 1)]
```

Or use the `labels` argument in `factor`

```
factor(df1$label, labels = c('-1', '+1'))
```

Or with `ifelse`

```
ifelse(df1$label>0, '+1', '-1')
```